# Cannot complete authorization

Tags: linkedin-api

I've got LinkedIn API app created and I'm able to get to the 'Allow' screen. That redirects to a form on my site which is submitted to linkedin.com to complete the authorization.
Instead of redirecting to my redirect url I'm getting an error saying:
"You must be authenticated to access this page".

Below is the form I'm submitting except that I've replaced the form field values with fakes.
I've made sure the real redirect URL is authenticated in my LinkedIn application.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SoftLink Systems LinkedIn Auth Completion</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmLNAuthComplete" action="https://www.linkedin.com" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code" />
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="FAKE_CODE_Gdy1R3cW2hFACX2dV39QwfofGVXg6v1nPH0O_Em4UnzEaR06ZXDGO57HU0DukpehS-EGu-AzF3L8SG8XfrB6oYRkpPtY3cLc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://linkedin.fake-domain.com/index.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="fake-id-k66l" />
    <input type="hidden" name="client_secret" value="fake-secret-rI2mxlqb" />
</form>
<script type="application/javascript">  
    var frm = document.querySelector("#frmLNAuthComplete"); 
    frm.submit();   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```